# Accessing variables outside foreach inside it in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a simple code sample in which i wanted to loop through directory contents :

```
$path = "C:\Users\BISWAJI\Desktop\Novels"

$content = dir -path $path | where { $_.Mode -match "^d.*" }

foreach ( $item in $content )
{
  "Items under the folder $path\$item are :"
  dir -path "$path\$item" | select name,mode
}
```

The trouble is the script is not able to read the variable $path inside foreach loop . Can anyone please give me any ideas? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` command should look like below. Notice that, you are missing a `echo` command for printing the line and you must separate both the different command using `;`

```
foreach ( $item in $content ) {"Items under the folder $path\$item are :"; dir -path "$path\$item" | select name,mode }
```

You can as well try this using `ForEach-Object` commandlet

```
dir -path $path | where { $_.Mode -match "^d.*" }|ForEach-Object {Write-Host "Items under the folder $path\$_ are :"; dir -path "$path\$_" | select name,mode}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i had done before right ? It is just in one line . i changed it as you suggested it is still not working :

Comment: The echo is not required btw. The default is to Write-Output.

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya, no you were missing the `;`. Moreover, I tried the same code in PowershellV2.0 and it works fine.

Comment: The way that you posted it the ; is not required either.

Comment: Its working directly from powershell prompt. I mean i define a variable $path , give it some value and then hit enter. And then if i execute this it works :

Comment: Having said all of that, the code posted by the OP works for me also

Comment: @EBGreen, yep I missed that and didn't tried to verify OP's code. In such case the question won't make sense.

Comment: It works now. Sorry my mistake . But in the output the "Name" and "Mode" banner comes only once at the very top and not after every echo statement . Is there any way to make it appear after every echo statement ?

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya, I don't think you can do that. You can use `| Format-List` to get header with every item display instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you, but your code runs fine on my system.

```
dir -path "C:\Users\BISWAJI\Desktop\Novels" | foreach { 
 if($_.PSIsContainer) { 
   dir -path $_.Fullname | select name,mode
 }
}
```